# Can I use statsD to scrape Kubernetes metric endpoint or from Kubernetes metric exporters?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

Can I use statsD to scrape Kubernetes metric endpoint or from Kubernetes metric exporters(for kubernetes infrastructure metrics like nodes, pods, control plane)?

I see people are using Prometheus more. I would like to know why StatsD don't typically not used in this case.